# Downloading Silently by Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need my extension to bulk download assess in a web page.

I set `saveAs:false` for `chrome.downloads.download` so that I do not get `saveAs` dialog. But when download starts, download bar at the bottom of the browser gets opened and all list of downloads puts into it. This clutters the download bar and Chrome interface.

Is it possible to prevent download bar from opening and not put the downloads that are started by an extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to hide the download bar (called **shelf** in Chrome UI lingo) completely, but not filter out specific downloads.

```
chrome.downloads.setShelfEnabled(false); // requires "downloads.shelf" permission
```

You can clear out your downloads from the download list with [`chrome.downloads.erase` method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-erase).

Consider an alternative (if more technically challenging) approach of "downloading" through XHR to a temporary [HTML5 FileSystem](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), forming an archive file, and then calling `chrome.downloads` on that. May not work if you need all the files immediately unpacked.

Comment: Thanks @Xan So you recommend `setShelfEnabled:false` before starting download, then `erase` the downloads and set back to `setShelfEnabled:true`? This is good but say if shelf is already open and user is downloading big ISO file to watch progress, he might not like the idea of another extension to close the download bar suddenly.

Comment: Indeed. It's a possible solution, but not a good solution. And one has to take extra care to make sure that the shelf is enabled again even if something goes wrong.

Comment: For HTML5 algorithm, I will check but would not chrome.downloads again put an entry in shelf?

Comment: It will, but I thought your concern was with flooding the shelf/list with many entries.

Comment: Hmm, thanks again, no actually I am looking for a silent download feature by the extension. Firefox allows such a silent feature. It is not for malicious reason. I just do not want to clutter the shelf and not opening shelf again and again which may cause user to close the shelf.

Comment: No such thing possible with Chrome API, I'm afraid. A Chrome App can write to disk silently after an initial access grant, but not interact with the browser. Unless you want to consider a hybrid extension+app architecture (which is clumsy from the user perspective) it's not possible to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Oh I see. Last question please, Can Chrome App write any folder in file system or is it just default downloads folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106349/discussion-between-xan-and-john-sewell).